# I can't install ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop

Tags: 13.04

I have HP pavilion g6 2010ax laptop running on windows 7 and i want to install ubuntu 13.04 . But problem is that when I select install ubuntu inside windows then suddenly my laptop goes shutdown...again if i reboot it same thing goes...I have tried many version like ubuntu 12.04 ,13.04 32 bit/64 bit but problem is same ....this may be happening because of AMD processor ...so plz help me

Comment: To install Ubuntu as a separate operating system with dual boot, you should create an install disk or USB stick and boot from it. See info [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (scroll down).

Comment: mubarak - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request your other accounts are merged.  Once done, you'll be able to edit your question again to give further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A variety of things can cause this but I would suspect first that an anti-virus
program is shutting it down. Turn off all anti-virus as well as Defender and
try to install but do so as Administrator. I strongly doubt that AMD graphics is
causing this.

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu by uninstalling bit defender anti virus ...but problem is same

Comment: I have done installation successfully.